# How can I speed up SteamCMD download?

Tags: steam, steamcmd

My app_update, on linux SteamCMD, is running extremely slow on my 100 MB/s network, so is there a way I could make it download faster? Maybe by changing the download location somehow? It also seems to be downloading in small chunks.

```
App state (0x300502) downloading, progress: 1.12 (43790472 / 3917687543)
App state (0x300502) downloading, progress: 1.12 (43790472 / 3917687543)
App state (0x300502) downloading, progress: 1.12 (43790472 / 3917687543)
App state (0x300502) downloading, progress: 1.12 (43790472 / 3917687543)
App state (0x300502) downloading, progress: 1.12 (43790472 / 3917687543)
App state (0x300502) downloading, progress: 1.12 (43790472 / 3917687543)
App state (0x300502) downloading, progress: 1.12 (43790472 / 3917687543)
App state (0x300502) downloading, progress: 1.12 (44069504 / 3917687543)
App state (0x300502) downloading, progress: 1.12 (44069504 / 3917687543)
App state (0x300502) downloading, progress: 1.12 (44069504 / 3917687543)
App state (0x300502) downloading, progress: 1.12 (44069504 / 3917687543)
App state (0x300502) downloading, progress: 1.12 (44069504 / 3917687543)
App state (0x300502) downloading, progress: 1.12 (44069504 / 3917687543)
App state (0x300502) downloading, progress: 1.12 (44069504 / 3917687543)
App state (0x300502) downloading, progress: 1.12 (44414420 / 3917687543)
App state (0x300502) downloading, progress: 1.12 (44414420 / 3917687543)
App state (0x300502) downloading, progress: 1.12 (44414420 / 3917687543)
App state (0x300502) downloading, progress: 1.12 (44414420 / 3917687543)
App state (0x300502) downloading, progress: 1.12 (44414420 / 3917687543)
App state (0x300502) downloading, progress: 1.12 (44414420 / 3917687543)
App state (0x300502) downloading, progress: 1.12 (44414420 / 3917687543)
App state (0x300502) downloading, progress: 1.12 (44414420 / 3917687543)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While downloading, make sure other people in your network aren't doing download-intensive things, such as YouTube and playing Steam games. Know that connection speeds also fluctuate throughout the day, especially in peak times.

(Are you sure that your download speed is 100 MB/s? That's probably your Ethernet downlink speed, not the speed you're paying for.)

There is also a possibility that the content server that SteamCMD is downloading from is under heavy load. Currently, there is no (documented) way of changing it.

If your server is being hosted somewhere else, talk with your host/ISP about the issue.

Comment: In my case, it's a dedicated line and not a home host.

Comment: @3ventic 100 MB/s dedicated lines are hard to find and extremely expensive. You should talk to your ISP/host to see if you're getting what you paid for.

Comment: Playing multiplayer games actually doesn't consume any bandwidth to speak of.

Comment: I think it was just a slow day for Steam overall. It works much faster now.